# My Rails 4 app config.eager_load = true will load activerecord datetime fields using Ruby Time class instead of ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activesupport

I just pushed a Rails 4 application to a new production env and noticed the timestamp is showed with UTC zone. They have been shown correctly in all other environment with PST , the Application config.time_zone I set in application.rb.
Further triaging the problem, I discovered that, in production env, the timestamp attributed is of Ruby class Time, not ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone

```
my_record.start_at.is_a?(ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone)
=>  false
```

But, in test env, the timestamp attributed is class ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone

```
my_record.start_at.is_a?(ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone)
=>  true
```

This is the same code base, and the vm was cloned from test, so the software versions are the same. I checked the production.rb file and didn't see anythings that changes this behavior.
I had

```
require 'rails/all'
```

in application.rb which should load all active support modules at start of app

The rest of the application seems to be working fine, so other active support classes must be loaded. Can someone help me to find out what was missing or changed in this particular env?

Thanks.

Update:
I decided to change my production.rb setting one at a time and found out that this is caused by

```
config.eager_load = true
```

When I change this value to false -- the ActiveSupport timezone is working again.
.. but I still cannot explain why the behavior changes when the class is pre-loaded. Any ideas?

Comment: Your issue does seem very strange I don't think I can help, but wanted to point you to a blog post I wrote about rails and timezones - http://jessehouse.com/blog/2013/11/15/working-with-timezones-and-ruby-on-rails/ - I would recommend using UTC instead of PST and overriding during each request - note PST is also not valid - it would be `'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'`

Comment: PST was what got displayed with strftime, config.time_zone is set to 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'